# Who Created the Community User. There is a Saying on Their Account that “They are not Really a Person”, But Who Made Their About Page?

Tags: discussion, election, profile-page, community-user, community

It has been interesting to see the robot user editing other people’s posts as if a person is editing them. I understand that there are a pattern of posts, but some of them seem human like. This naturally brings up the question who created Community on the main and meta stack exchanges.

In addition, they are a moderator which means that they have more privileges than the normal user. However, they still have only 1 reputation despite upvoting their questions does nothing and downvoting obviously does not bring theirs down because nobody’s reputation on the website can go down below 1.

**Main question:**

**The two main questions discussed here are who created the profile for Community, and who created the original election question of around 2014?**

Here is a link to their [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community).

Comment: Please tell me why the downvote. I have shortened the question.

Comment: Request to not worry about downvotes, only close votes on meta should be a sign. Downvotes are a sign that somebody does not agree that this is a useful question, but posts without consensus are going to be the norm on meta. Please search for more material on meta regarding the community user, using the search box. Of course your answer need not be there, but it'll be good to be as self-informed as possible.

Comment: See [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738) at [metase]. This and other links you might find useful can be found in the [tag info](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/community-user/info) of the meta tag [meta-tag:community-user].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Community user is mostly a token in a data base.

The edits done by the community user are for the most part suggested edits that were proposed and approved by users. In rare cases SE starts some automated mass edit and that is also attributed to this user.

Other than that actions by deleted user accounts get transferred to Community user. It is also possible  for users to get a post disassociated from a post,  then it becomes one of the community user (though it does not show up in the profil). And there are some other things.

The short is, there is no artificial intelligence or anything behind it. The Community user is part of the technical design of the site. It's there to have a user account that can be associated to certain actions that usually are carried out by users but sometimes are not.